# Reuse part of RxJava stream

Tags: rx-java, rx-java2, rx-kotlin, rx-kotlin2

Probably an rx newbee question.

If I have two rx streams, which have some common parts, is there a possibility to extract and to reuse them?

Here is pseudo code example:

```
someManager.getInfo(id) returns a Single<SometInfo>
```

This fun takes an id and should return just a single with status

```
fun getStatus(id: String): Single<Status> =
    someManager.getInfo(id)
        .flattenAsObservable { it.items }
        .map { getSomeProp(it) } // from here
        .toList()
        .map { getStatus(it) }
        .doOnSuccess { getStatusRelay(id).accept(it) } // until here it's common
```

and this one doesn't take an id but already an object and should check if a status is ok

```
fun isStatusOk(info: SomeInfo): Single<Boolean> =
    Observable.fromIterable(info.items)
        .map { getSomeProp(it) } // from here
        .toList()
        .map { getStatus(it) }
        .doOnSuccess { getStatusRelay(id).accept(it) } // until here it's common
        .map { it == Status.OK }
```

Thank you in advance

Comment: Are you looking for an `ObservableTransformer`?

Comment: Thank you. Maybe ... at least it looks like this, but I couldn't apply any changes.

Comment: @PhoenixWang ok. I've got it working

Answer (score 1):

You can also use extend function

```
fun Observable<Item>.convertToSingeStatus(): Single<Status> =
        this.map { getSomeProp(it) }
            .toList()
            .map { getStatus(it) }
            .doOnSuccess { getStatusRelay(id).accept(it) }
```

And then

```
fun getStatus(id: String): Single<Status> =
someManager.getInfo(id)
    .convertToSingeStatus()
    .doOnSuccess { getStatusRelay(id).accept(it) }
```

Comment: do we really need doOnSuccess twice?

Answer (score 0):

Phoenix Wang suggested Transformers. I tried them and after some experiments it seems I got it working.

I created a SingleTransformer:

```
private fun getStatus() =
    SingleTransformer<SomeInfo, Status> {
        it.flatMap {
            Observable.fromIterable(it.items)
                .map { getSomeProp(it) }
                .toList()
                .map { getStatus(it) }
        }
    }
```

And then I can refactor

```
fun getStatus(id: String): Single<Status> =
    someManager.getInfo(id)
        .compose(getStatus())
        .doOnSuccess { getStatusRelay(id).accept(it) }
```

and this too

```
fun isStatusOk(info: SomeInfo): Single<Boolean> =
    Single.just(info)
        .compose(getStatus())
        .doOnSuccess { getStatusRelay(id).accept(it) }
        .map { it == Status.OK }
```

Hopefully it helps someone else.